# Change cell colours on a google sheet via script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet which is constantly updated ( via a script), containing a large amount of numbers.

To make the data easier to read, I would like to forat the cell colours, depending on the value of the cell to the immediate left.

green if higher
red if lower
amber if the same

So for example, if my cells contains;

10,20,100,5,5

20 would be green
100 would be green
5 would be red
16 would be amber

I have an existing script in place which is on a loop handling multiple sheets, so I would like to apply the formatting at the point the data is pasted into the cell;

Below is the portion of code which populates cells, and where I would like it to query the value of the cell to the immediate left.

```
for (var sheet of sheets) {
        //sheet.getRange(targetcell)
        //    .setValue('=--SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN(",",IMPORTDATA(B1)),"LCPrice"":""(.*)"), CHAR(34))')

            sheet.getRange(targetcell).setValue('=--SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN(",",IMPORTDATA(B1)),"LCPrice"":""(.*)"), CHAR(34))');
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    range.copyTo(range, { contentsOnly: true });
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Looks like a perfect task for conditional formatting https://www.howtogeek.com/737992/how-to-apply-a-color-scale-based-on-values-in-google-sheets/

Comment: I can't see any way to do this in conditional formatting....must have watched 20 advanced conditional formatting videos, but I dont think its possible.

What I was thinking I could do is use a var 'colour', and set the var to a colour based on a formula like if currentcell<cell to the left colour=green

Then use .setBackground("colour")

Just dont know how to do it.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean 'I would like to forat the cell colours'. Do what? Show your desired table. With those colors and numbers. Show us how should it look like.

Comment: hi yuri,  Ive spent 20 minutes trying to work out how to mark your kind help as an answer....I dont have the option...nor to vote for your answer.

Comment: My answer? Here is none of my (or any) answers. Only couple comments, for now. Because, I suspect, nobody has been able to figure out what is your question about.